# SQL запрос в потоке Delphi

Tags: sql, delphi, многопоточность

Имеется вот такая конструкция:

```
var
  oXml: IXMLDocument;
begin
  try
    Query1.Open;

    if xmlForm.Query1.Fields[0].Value > 0 then
    begin
      MessageBox(Self.Handle, PChar(VarToStr(Query1.Fields[1].Value)), PChar('Внимание!'),
        MB_OK + MB_ICONWARNING + MB_APPLMODAL);
    end
    else
    begin
      oXml := TXMLDocument.create(nil);
      oXml.XML.Text := VarToStr(Query1.Fields[1].Value);
      oXml.XML.Text := XMLDoc.FormatXMLData(oXml.XML.Text);
      oXml.Active := true;
      SynMemo1.Text := oXml.XML.Text;
    end;
  except
    On e: EDatabaseError do
      messageDlg(e.message, mtError, [mbOK], 0);
  end;
end;
```

Естественно при выполнении его выполнении форма не реагирует на действия пользователя.
Пытался сделать через потоки, но результат мне не ясен.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  new1 := tnew.create(true);
  new1.freeonterminate := true;
  new1.priority := tpNormal;
  new1.resume;
end; 

procedure tnew.execute;
var
  oXml: IXMLDocument;
  v: Integer;
begin
  try
    xmlForm.Query1.Open;

    v := xmlForm.Query1.Fields[0].Value;
    if v = 0 then
    begin
      oXml := TXMLDocument.create(nil);
      oXml.XML.Text := VarToStr(xmlForm.Query1.Fields[1].Value);
      oXml.XML.Text := XMLDoc.FormatXMLData(oXml.XML.Text);
      oXml.Active := true;
      xmlForm.SynMemo1.Text := oXml.XML.Text;
    end
    else
    begin
      MessageBox(Self.Handle, PChar(VarToStr(xmlForm.Query1.Fields[1].Value)), PChar('Внимание!'),
        MB_OK + MB_ICONWARNING + MB_APPLMODAL);
    end;
  except
    On e: EDatabaseError do
      messageDlg(e.message, mtError, [mbOK], 0);message объекта e
  end;
end;
```

Т.е.

```
MessageBox(Self.Handle, PChar(VarToStr(xmlForm.Query1.Fields[1].Value)), PChar('Внимание!'),
            MB_OK + MB_ICONWARNING + MB_APPLMODAL);
```

выдается раз через раз в случае v=1.

Прошу вашей помощи.

Comment: Все действия над визуальными объектами должны выполняться в основном потоке.  В особенности - присвоение значений. Минимально - необходимо строку `SynMemo1.Text :=` обернуть в TThread.Queue или TThread.Synchronize. MessageDlg тоже не место в доп.потоке.  @All - а есть какой-нибудь "канонический" ответ про многопоточность, в частности - работу с визуальными элементами?

Answer (score 1):

Одно из основополагающих правил при работе с дополнительными потоками - никогда не взаимодействовать в их контексте с визуальными элементами. Всё, что относится к формам / вторичным окнам и лежит на них должно вызываться из основного потока. Если всё же необходимо такое обращение - вызов визуальных элементов должен идти через методы синхронизации, например TThread.Queue и TThread.Synchronize, которые "переключат" выполнение в основной поток и выполнят необходимые действия в его контексте.

Предполагая,что основное время занимает именно обращение к базе (выборка данных), код следует переписать примерно следующим образом (для конкретики предположим, что для обращения к БД используется ADO. Для других видов подключений изменить не должно быть сложно):

```pascal
procedure TMyThread.Execute;
var
  Conn: TADOConnection;
  Qry: TADOQuery;
  v: Integer;
  XML: IXMLDocument;
begin
  try
    Conn := TADOConnection.Create; // подключение к БД должно быть своего потока
    try
      Conn.LoginPrompt := False;
      Conn.ConnectionString := 'своя строка подключения';

      Qry := TADOQuery.Create; // а равно и запрос, работающий с этим подключением
      try
        Qry.Connection := Conn;
        Qry.Sql.Text := 'SELECT Field1, Field2 FROM myTable WHERE...';
        Qry.Open;
        try
          if Qry.EOF then
            Exit;

          if Qry.Fields[0].AsInteger = 0 then // избавляемся от V, она лишняя
            begin
              XML := LoadXMLData(Qry.Fields[1].AsString);
              // дальше именно здесь - необходимые преобразования
              // с XML документом
              // подавляющее большинство работы может и должно проводиться
              // в этом доп.потоке. В основном потоке - только вывод итоговой
              // информации.
              Synchronize(
                procedure
                begin
                  xmlForm.SynMemo1.Text := oXml.XML.Text;
                end);
            end
          else
            Synchronize(
              procedure
              begin
                MessageBox(. .. 'внимание!', .. .);
              end);
        finally
          Qry.Close;
        end;
      finally
        Qry.Free; // кто создал - тот и удаляет
      end;
    finally
      Conn.Free;
    end;
  except
    on e: EDatabaseError do
      Synchronize(
        procedure
        begin
          MessageBox(... 'Ошибка!', .. .);
        end);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: А с запуском потока, как уже упомянули в соседнем ответе, он не верен. Могу я узнать ваше мнение по поводу верного запуска и остановки потока?

Comment: @idrees `FreeOnTerminate` - это нормально для потока, который выполняет однократную операцию, т.е. execute не зациклен (допустим) в выборке сообщений и т.п. Например, **штатная** конструкция `TThread.CreateAnonimousThread` выставляет FreeOnTerminate в True. Ограничения, безусловно, есть. Но они по большому счету не зависят от того выставлено FreeOnTerminate или нет.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
procedure TNew.Execute;
var
  oXml: IXMLDocument;
  v: Integer;
begin
    Synchronize(procedure
      begin
        xmlForm.Query1.Open;
        v := xmlForm.Query1.Fields[0].Value;
      end
    );

    if v = 0 then
    begin
      oXml := TXMLDocument.create(nil);

      Synchronize(procedure
        begin
          oXml.XML.Text := VarToStr(xmlForm.Query1.Fields[1].Value);
        end
      );

      oXml.XML.Text := XMLDoc.FormatXMLData(oXml.XML.Text);
      oXml.Active := true;

      Synchronize(procedure
        begin
          xmlForm.SynMemo1.Text := oXml.XML.Text;
        end
      );
    end
    else
    begin
      Synchronize(procedure
        begin
          xmlForm.SynMemo1.Text := VarToStr(xmlForm.Query1.Fields[1].Value); // вместо MessageBox
        end
      );
    end;
end;
```

Создавать потоки и отпускать их в свободное плавание (как у вас происходит в  Button1Click) очень нехорошо. Я бы вообще запретил пользоваться свойством `FreeOnTerminate`.

---

**UPD**

Поток нужно запускать сразу при создании, т.е. `.Create(False)`. Если нужно передать параметры потоку, перекрывайте конструктор своим вариантом и передавайте туда все нужные параметры. Ссылку на созданный экземпляр нужно хранить в переменной. При этом, если создание происходит по нажатию кнопки, то обязательно нужно проверить нет ли в переменной ссылки на уже созданный и работающий поток. Иначе будет утечка памяти или как минимум потеряете ссылку на предыдущий поток. Поток после своей работы должен каким-то образом сообщить основному потоку о том, что он закончил свою работу. Например, отправить сообщение в главное окно или предоставить какое-то свое публичное свойство значение которого будет говорить о том работает ли еще поток. Поток в своей работе должен периодически проверять свойство `Terminated`, чтобы узнать о том, что результат его работы уже никому не нужен и ему пора срочно завершать свою работу. В идеале для этих целей использовать ожидаемое событие `TEvent`. Деструктор потока пишем свой таким образом:

```
begin
  Terminate;  // сообщаем потоку, что ему нужно завершить свою работу
  if not Suspended then  // если поток уже запустился (не приостанавливался)
    WaitFor;  // подождем его завершения

  // здесь нужно уничтожать объекты, которыми владеет поток

  inherited Destroy;
end;
```

А в основном потоке (или кто там владеет потоком), когда поток больше не нужен, просто вызываем `MyThread.Free;` или `FreeAndNil(MyThread);`.

В таком случае, если работа потока занимает значительное время, а пользователь устал ждать и, например, закрыл программу, то программа не будет висеть в процессах до тех пор пока не завершится неконтролируемый поток (если он вообще завершится).

Comment: Весь код в синхронайзе :) И except-блок не отработает, потому что db-исключение возникнет в главном потоке.

Comment: :) какой вопрос - такой ответ. По правильному нужно весь поток переделать. А это просто, быстро-костыль. Насчет исключения согласен, не обратил внимания :)

Comment: @kot-da-vinci Спасибо за ваш ответ! Скажите, как правильнее всего запускать поток и как я понял завершать его?

Comment: @idrees дополнил ответ пояснениями про работу с потоками.

Comment: С учетом ожидаемого использования TEvent - деструктор надо доработать, иначе получится ДедЛок. Остальные утверждения тоже достаточно спорны в том плане, что нельзя их воспринимать как аксиому, это всего лишь один из вариантов работы с потоками. Правильный вариант можно подсказать только зная, что должен делать поток и в каком "окружении" ему предстоит работать

Comment: Это безусловно не аксиома, а просто хороший тон. В новых версиях delphi у `TThread` добавился пустой виртуальный протектед метод `TerminatedSet` который вызывается из метода `Terminate`. Самый логичный способ, перекрыть этот метод в своем наследнике и включать там `TEvent`. В таком случае деструктор дорабатывать не нужно. При этом этот Event обязательно должен создаваться с параметром ManualReset = true.